# Should I go for this girl?

Tags: nikah, friendship

so there is a girl I like and I want to go for Nikkah but we were in contact before so few things happened due to which I lost my trust and I don't know what am I supposed to do now? Should I go for Nikkah or not?

So she had male friends before and I told to leave them all and I gave her more than a month but she didn't then I blocked them all myself. After a couple of months one of her friends somehow sent her a message that he wants to talk to her, she asked me and I didn't give her permission but after a few days we had a small clash and she went for it and talked to him  after resolving the clash I asked her and she told me that she did it. After a month, we again had a small clash and she again talked to her secretly and somehow I found it, on asking at first she was denying but then she accepted it. Also, she asked me to talk to a guy from whom she wanted to talk some help but the help converted into a sweet conversation and on telling her to stop she started fighting me. All these things made me so insecure and now I am thinking if I Nikkah her and she does something like this again then? We both are going for the same university and she told me to give her permission to talk to guys for just help only (no friendship or frankness) but I am so insecure and she is willing to leave me if I don't give her permission.

I know having such kind of relation is Haram so I decided to go for Nikkah but I am so confused. Please Suggest me something.

Answer (score 1):

You must decide anything in the light of Islam, so regarding your Question keep in mind some important points.

Hadith:

**Hudhaifah reported the Messenger of Allah (صلی اللہ علیہ وسلم) as saying: A mischief-maker will not enter paradise.
(Abi Dawud)**

- So you might not think negative about anyone(her). It is Haram.
- Another thing is that by forgiving the mistakes of others, Allah
  forgives your mistakes

Now regarding your situation(you clearly mentioned everything), as you said that she cheated you more than once. It is my personal advice to you brother Don't go for Nikah with her. Mostly, such type of marriages cannot be successful as you now don't trust her. You must not be married to her.

We must follow the commandment of **اللہ عزوجل** and Prophet **محمد صلی علیہ وسلم.**

So, You forgave her for once or twice. Now you have done your job. You should go back to **اللہ عزوجل** and pray for your bright future.